# ECONNRESET happens every 2 hours for connection to redis use nodejs

Tags: node.js, redis

I use [redis](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis) module to connect redis.

```
const Promise = require("bluebird");
const redis = require("redis");

Promise.promisifyAll(redis.RedisClient.prototype);
Promise.promisifyAll(redis.Multi.prototype);

var RedisClient = redis.createClient("192.168.59.101", 6379);

RedisClient.on("connect", () => {
    logger.info("connect to redis success");
});

RedisClient.on("error", err => {
    console.error(err);
});
```

ECONNRESET happens every 2 hours:

```
{
    "syscall": "read",
    "code": "ECONNRESET",
    "errno": "ECONNRESET"
}
```

This problem seems to be related to [TCP keepalive](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/usingkeepalive.html) because tcp_keepalive_time is 7200 seconds, which is exactly 2 hours.

```sh
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive_time
7200
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: process.on('uncaughtException', (e) => console.error(e));